# Cross-platform socket send, buffer const void* on linux const char* on windows, best way to handle?

Tags: c++, sockets, cross-platform

I am porting a program which uses posix (BSD) sockets to windows (using winsock). This is going ok, but I have come up against an issue with `send` (I think `recv` might have the same issue). On Linux this function has the signature (see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send)):

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

on windows it is (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
int send(
  _In_       SOCKET s,
  _In_ const char   *buf,
  _In_       int    len,
  _In_       int    flags
);
```

The first place I have a problem is in a destructor like this:

```
ExtSocketHandler::~ExtSocketHandler(void)
{
    if (pUS->GetSock() >= 0) {
        uint8_t u = ES_ABORT;

        // ignore result
        (void)send(pUS->GetSock(), (void *)&u, sizeof(u), send_flags);
    }
    SAFEDELETE(pUS);
}
```

where the line

```
(void)send(pUS->GetSock(), (void *)&u, sizeof(u), send_flags);
```

results in a compiler error on windows as `void*` cannot be cast to `const char*`.

Now I suppose I can wrap all calls to send in an `#ifdef` for windows, but is this the best way to handle this? Is there a more elegant way? There are quite a few calls to `send` and `recv` to deal with.

Comment: Cast to `const char*`?

Comment: BTW, since type `SOCKET` is unsigned on Windows, you can't do `if (pUS->GetSock() >= 0)`. Compare it with `INVALID_SOCKET` instead.

Comment: @Tulon, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @crobar If you want to check for invalid / unitialized socket, use the `INVALID_SOCKET` constant, and define it to `-1` if it is not already defined (non-windows systems).

Comment: There is never a need to cast anything to `void *`. If you think there is, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @EJP, this was the original code, I'm just porting it, but good to know, not sure what happens if you just remove the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to `const char *`, it should compile on both platforms